# C++ How to read txt file and retrieve numerical values, apart from string (and vice versa)

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I have been teaching myself C++, and searching for how to do this. Let me give an example to clarify my intention.

Here is a txt file, and the content is following.

```
Matt   18  180.0   88.5
Angela 20  155.5   42.2
```

Each row has information about a person's name, age, height and weight.

What I've been trying to do is to get those 4 types of information separately and store them in different variables, based on the information type.

```
vector<string> name; //"Matt" or "Angela" are stored here.
vector<int> age; //18 or 20
vector<double> height; //The same logic goes for this vector and the next one
vector<double> weight;
```

At least I've found that information inside txt files can be stored in string variables by using `ifstreamObject.open(filename.c_str())` and `getline(ifstreamObject, string)`. However, by using this method, I'd get only string values which correspond to each row. In other words, I cannot distinguish string values from numeric values.

Chances are that there isn't any other way to get information from txt files. Nonetheless, just in case, I'd like to ask some advice here on how to get information in such a way, before I give up.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is to use the stream directly,

```
std::string name;
int age;
double height, weight;

while(ifstreamObject >> name >> age >> height >> weight)
{
    // process name, age, height and weight
}
```

The downside is that the stream insertion operator will read until the first whitespace. So, if you want to read a whole line as a string, then use `getline`, process the string accordingly, "map" back the string read by `getline` into a `istringstream`,

```
std::istringstream is(str); // constructs an istringstream from the string str
```

then use `is` similarly to how you'd use a stream.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can I ask one more question? The `>>` operator apparently separates each string block (In the example above, each string block can be "Matt" , "18", "180.0" and so on), based on whether there is a space or not. I also think that I need to put a variable's name between `>>`, in order to detect each string block. Am I correct? Googling `c++ ifstream >> operator` shows results which are related `c++ istream >> operator`, not `ifstream`.

Comment: @YMD yes, that's correct. And the extraction operator is inherited from `istream` (which is a base class of `ifstream`).

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there is a certain Character between each entry (like a tab) you could use String.find_first_of and substrings to divide the string into pieces and parse them into the fields you have.
Check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ for more info

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use stl::string methods to manipulate row string to extract those 4 types of information separately.

use [`std::string::find_first_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/) to find each start of white space and use [`std::string::find_first_not_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_not_of/) to find each non white space characters. use [`std::string::substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) to extract sub string from row string. Also use `atoi` to convert string value to int.

for example,

`//rowSrting holds the data of one line in file`

```
std::size_t nameEnd = rowString.find_first_of(" ");
string name = rowString.substr(0, nameEnd-1);

std::size_t ageFirst = rowString.find_first_not_of(" ", nameEnd);
std::size_t ageEnd = rowString.find_first_of(" ", ageFirst );
int age = atoi(rowString.substr(ageFirst, ageEnd-1));
```